# Bypassing operating system and drawing to frame buffer of GPU

Tags: graphics, operating-system, gpu, x11, framebuffer

Is it possible to directly modify frame buffer of a GPU without using any operating system or OpenGl/directX calls but just GPU driver calls?

Basically I want to overlay some animations on my screen and don't want operating system to overwrite any pixels of it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible by using the [Dumb-Buffer API](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man7/drm-memory.7.html) of the [DRM (Direct Rendering Manager)](https://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/DRM/) driver.

You should definitely see David Herrmann's [tutorials](https://dvdhrm.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/linux-drm-mode-setting-api/) and [download](https://github.com/dvdhrm/docs/tree/master/drm-howto) his examples. He only forgot to initialize the gamma ramps.